# Django rest framework slow response time

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am working on a project. I am using **Django rest framework**.

I have a category model. And there is only 2 rows. And the api response time is 180 ms avarage.

it is **too slow** for only 2 rows. And api is **very simple**. Why it is too slow for such a simple api.

**here is my view**

```
class CategoryListView(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = Category.objects.order_by('order').all()
    serializer_class = CategorySerializer

    def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        queryset = self.filter_queryset(self.get_queryset())
        print(queryset.query)
        serializer = self.get_serializer(queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

**here is my serializer**

```
class CategorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Category
        fields = ("id", "name", "order")
```

And here is the query generated.

```
SELECT "questions_category"."id", "questions_category"."created_at", "questions_category"."updated_at", "questions_category"."name", "questions_category"."name_tk", "questions_category"."name_ru", "questions_category"."icon", "questions_category"."order" FROM "questions_category" ORDER BY "questions_category"."order" ASC
```

I am analyzing it with **django-silk**

query time is **6 ms**.

but response time is **180 ms**

Could somebody help me with this?

Comment: is your application and database on the same network? and if they are (assuming they are on a cloud provider), are you making the request on the same location?

Comment: @BrianDestura yes they are on the same server

Comment: @BrianDestura I measured it with django-silk. there it shows overall time 12ms avarage. but response time is 180ms avarage